# how to run asmx webservice on ubuntu/linux?

Tags: c#, linux, web-services, ubuntu, asmx

i have a running webserver with ubuntu. (on ec2 instance)

i also have an asmx webservice i created with c#.

i want use this setup to connect between the webserver and couchbase. (but its not very important for the question itself)

1. is it possible (im guessing yes) to load that asmx(lets call it a file) to run on ubuntu?
2. what are the best tools/frameworks to deploy asmx webservice on ubuntu?
3. is there a reason why i should not do that, and deploy it on a windows based server instead?
   (like performance, ease of use etc)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) is it possible (im guessing yes) to load that asmx(lets call it a file) to run on ubuntu?

Yes, you could use [`Mono`](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

> 2) what are the best tools/frameworks to deploy asmx webservice on ubuntu?

Hard to talk about best tools or frameworks. But you could [`run ASP.NET application on Apache`](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

> 3) is there a reason why i should not do that, and deploy it on a windows based server instead? (like performance, ease of use etc)

Yes, the native home of .NET applications is Windows. Mono can only follow the evolution and new features that get introduced in the .NET framework on Windows.