# Deploy / host asmx webservice on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, web-services, asmx

I can't find any tutorial on how to deploy / host an asp.net web service on a Linux environment.

Does someone have a clue on how to do so please ?

Comment: It is possible to host a .net core application on linux. What have you tried. What specific errors are you seeing?

Comment: Like the other comment said, migrate your project to ASP.NET Core and run it directly on Linux. Don't waste your time on ASP.NET 4.x on Mono.

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539525/how-to-run-asmx-webservice-on-ubuntu-linux